# simple code to connect to remote linux without python library

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

The code works but it still asking for the password in cmd:

```
import subprocess
import os, sys
password='password'
    
args = ['ssh', '-p', 'ssh', 'user@<ip>', 'ls']
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    
proc.stdin.write('password\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.close()
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    
print (stdout)
```

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: `ssh` reads its password directly from the terminal, not standard input.

Comment: @nitz: What's the question, how to pass the password to ssh ?

Comment: set up a key based authentication ..

Comment: @rasjani tbh I'd rather use a password to connect on a remote machine than using a password-less private key.

Comment: @ShellCode Why? Public key authentication is not that hard to set up, and is more secure than trying to feed your password in clear text via standard input.

Comment: I'm not saying it's hard to setup, I'm saying there's not much difference between password input (considering it cannot easily be bruteforced, a strong password basically) and password-less private key. Both are terrible. But at least the password we type in when we SSH is volatile and resides only in memory for a few micro-seconds, while a password-less private key resides on disk. If someone steals your laptop he also has access to your server thanks to your password-less private key. But you're right, hardcoding the password in source code is just as bad (ok maybe a bit worst).

Comment: You can use a password for the ssh key based authentication if you have ssh-agent running.. Authenticate it once and key is available for without a password after that ..

Answer (score 0):

The SSH client utility does not read the password from the standard input. Probably to stop people from doing what you're trying to do.

You should really consider using an ssh lib for that. But if you really insist on doing it without an external library, you will at least have to use the [standard `pty` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) to hook SSH's controlling terminal.

From the official documentation :

> pty.spawn(argv[, master_read[, stdin_read]])
>
> Spawn a process, and connect its controlling terminal with the current process’s standard io. This is often used to baffle programs which insist on reading from the controlling terminal.

Also, hardcoding passwords in source code is a pretty bad idea, take a look at the [standard getpass module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html).